# What is wrong with this regex, not working correctly?

Tags: c#, regex, oracle, string-literals

My query is working fine inside my oracle, but when I add it inside my oracle command getting error at [A-Z] and \1\3 saying unrecognized character. I think I need to use @ some where to make it correct but I don't know where?

***My Query to see definition of trigger without user name: also deleting line that start with ALTER TRIGGER.. ***

```
OracleCommand Command = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT regexp_replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER','" + triggernames + "'),'(CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER )("[A-Z]+"\.)(.+)(ALTER TRIGGER .+)','\1\3', 1, 0, 'n')FROM dual", connection))
```

***Result:***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "USER"."EMP"
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    of salary
    on employee
    for each row
   declare
       v_error VARCHAR2(20);
    begin
       if :new.salary > 10
      then
           v_error:=:old.first_name||' cannot have that much!';
           raise_application_error(-20999,v_error);
       end if;
end;
ALTER TRIGGER "USER"."EMP" ENABLE
```

***Expected Result:***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "EMP"
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    of salary
    on employee
    for each row
   declare
       v_error VARCHAR2(20);
    begin
       if :new.salary > 10
      then
           v_error:=:old.first_name||' cannot have that much!';
           raise_application_error(-20999,v_error);
       end if;
end;
```

Comment: Better not concatenate strings in sql commands, use prepared statements instead i.e. `OracleCommand Command = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT regexp_replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER',:triggernames),'(CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER )(""[A-Z]+""\.)(.+)(ALTER TRIGGER .+)','\1\3', 1, 0, 'n')FROM dual", connection));`

Answer (score 1):

@ Won't do all the escaping for you. You need to escape the quotes around [A-Z] with '\'.

Same deal with the \1\3, '\' is saying it's an escape sequence where you really mean a literal '\'.

E.g:

```
OracleCommand Command = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT regexp_replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER','" + triggernames + "'),'(CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER )(\"[A-Z]+\"\.)(.+)(ALTER TRIGGER .+)','\\1\\3', 1, 0, 'n')FROM dual", conn1))
```

Alternatively if you want to use a 2nd '@' you need to use the quote-escape-sequence (a double "")

e.g.:

```
@"SELECT regexp_replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER','" + triggernames + @"'),'(CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER )(""[A-Z]+""\.)(.+)(ALTER TRIGGER .+)','\1\3', 1, 0, 'n')FROM dual"
```

Comment: Is it still the same error? Or is it just the regex itself isn't doing what you expected now?

Comment: @user2760129, are you sure it's the regexp? could it be the value in `triggernames` (upper/lower case or something like that) ?